# OnClientSelectedIndexChanged not firing on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, frontend, telerik

My OnClientSelectedIndexChanged javascript function is not firing when the dropdown selected value is changed. I've put a breakpoint on the first line of the javascript function and it is never reached.

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">       
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function ddl_AutoSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventargs) {
                var date_DueDate = $find("#date_DueDate");
                var date_PlannedStart = $find("#date_PlannedStart");
                var date_PlannedFinish = $find("#date_PlannedFinish");
                date_DueDate.value = Now.AddDays(sender.value);
                date_PlannedStart.value = Now.AddDays(0);
                date_PlannedFinish.value = Now.AddDays(sender.value);
            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

And my dropdown:

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddl_AutoSchedule" runat="server" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_AutoSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <Items>
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="0" Text="Select a Schedule" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="30" Text="30 Days" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="45" Text="45 Days" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="60" Text="60 Days" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="90" Text="90 Days" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="120" Text="120 Days" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="180" Text="180 Days (6 Months)" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="270" Text="270 Days (9 Months)" />
     <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="365" Text="365 Days (1 Year)" />
  </Items>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the samples in the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/events/onclientselectedindexchanged), there is no need to wrap your JS function with a `RadCodeBlock` control.

Just write the `<script>` block to the page and it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function ddl_AutoSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventargs) 
    {
        var date_DueDate = $find("#date_DueDate");
        var date_PlannedStart = $find("#date_PlannedStart");
        var date_PlannedFinish = $find("#date_PlannedFinish");
        date_DueDate.value = Now.AddDays(sender.value);
        date_PlannedStart.value = Now.AddDays(0);
        date_PlannedFinish.value = Now.AddDays(sender.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried your solution to no avail. In fact, the debugger says that it's impossible for my breakpoint to be hit. So confused...

Comment: @SethD02 I personally don't use VS for JS breakpoints. Use your browser Dev tools to set a breakpoint instead (in Sources) and let me know if it is hit.

Comment: I was able to get it to hit the breakpoint using Dev tools, thank you. Turns out the controls are not being found using the $find

Comment: Are you using a `ToolkitScriptManager `?